# How to awake Emacs GUI after pressing Ctrl+z

Tags: emacs, gnome, gui

I'm using Emacs GUI in Gnome. After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, the Emacs window is minimized. However, if I bring the window to the front, it doesn't respond to any key press or mouse event. I searched the web and only found how to bring it back from the command line.

How do I reactivate Emacs when using it in GUI mode?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you press `C-z` by mistake then you can add this to your .emacs to make C-z do nothing:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-z"))
```

I did that after pressing C-z many times by accident.

Comment: resize the window (as posted below) to fix now! And then do this to make it permanent. Thanks from someone who has to constantly switch German and US keyboard layout.

Comment: Both C-z and C-x C-z are typically bound to `(suspend-frame)`. If you unset C-z, you can still suspend with a C-x before C-z. (I consider this to be a feature but some may take that as inspiration to `(global-unset-key (kbd "C-x C-z"))`.)

Comment: Useful but doesn't answer the actual question.

Answer (score 21):

Type

```
fg
```

or

```
fg %emacs
```

to get Emacs back.

Answer (score 8):

You may have to send the process a `SIGCONT` signal. You normally do this in the console by running `kill -CONT $emacs_pid` or `killall -CONT emacs`. If you insist on a GUI solution, you can try the task manager shipped with your distro.

Answer (score 7):

Send it a `CONT` signal:

```
killall -CONT emacs
```

A **`WINCH`** signal also seems to work, so you can **just resize the Emacs window**.

Clicking on any menu items seems to work as well.

If you were running Emacs from a terminal, `fg` ("foreground") or `%emacs` would work.

Answer (score 1):

C-s resumes a GUI Emacs after C-z

Answer (score 0):

Try using a window resize command.  I was using X11 forwarding to forward the Emacs GUI from a Linux server to my computer (Windows).  Hitting `C-z` minimized the window, and when I brought it back up Emacs had frozen, but resizing it using the Windows key (e.g., <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>) unfroze it and it started responding again.