# emacs term send literal C-z to bash (background running process)

Tags: emacs, job-control

I recently switch from cli emacs to gui emacs (25). I regularly use a `M-x term` buffer to run cli tools. Upon switching, I found that pressing `C-z` now minimizes the emacs window (and laughed at the literal port of the "background" feature), even when focusing the term buffer. I found [this question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/349943/how-to-awake-emacs-gui-after-pressing-ctrlz#349997) that propose a way to make `C-z` do nothing, which does what it says, but is not what I want. I want the running program in the term buffer to move into the background, the same as it would if `C-z` were pushed in a normal terminal emulator. I also found [this](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/2345) conversation about sending a literal `C-r` in evil mode, which is not applicable because I am not using evil mode.

e: here's my .emacs

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (manoj-dark)))
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (multi-term slime magit ess))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(load "dired")

(global-linum-mode)
(global-auto-revert-mode)

(setq desktop-path '("."))
(desktop-save-mode 1)

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

(put 'upcase-region 'disabled nil)
(put 'downcase-region 'disabled nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: uninstall multi-term. I had installed it but was not using it. It was being loaded by a config in .emacs.d, and just loading it apparently messes up the key bindings in plain old term.